# Oracle SQL Developer ERD not automatically Include Relationship Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

For example, I have tables below:

- employee (emp_id PK, name, ...)
- attendance (att_id PK, emp_id FK, ....)

In Oracle SQL Developer, 
when I drag and drop the employee table into the Relational, it is not automatically included the attendance table.

Is there an option to enable (automatically included the relationship tables)?

[image]

Comment: Version of sqldev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When you drag over your 'driving' table, CTRL+CLICK and Drag to the Modeling area.

[image]

[Full description here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/how-to-generate-an-erd-for-selected-tables-in-sql-developer/)

Comment: Great news @bunthai!